# CakePHP: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying this code:

## My Code snippet

```
public function beforeFind($query) {
        $query = parent::beforeFind($query);
        if(!isset($query['conditions'])){
            $query['conditions'] = array();
        }
        if(!$this->Authake->isAdmin()){
            if(empty($query['conditions']) || is_array($query['conditions'])){
                $query['conditions'] = array('organ_id' => $this->Organ->Group->getUserBranches());
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

But I am getting this error

## Error

```
Warning (2): Cannot use a scalar value as an array [APP\Model\Ticket.php, line 56]

Warning (2): Cannot use a scalar value as an array [APP\Model\Ticket.php, line 56]
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this _at all_? `$query` is obviously not an array but a scalar value, most probably boolean `true`.

Comment: which line is #56? most likely your parent::beforeFind returns a boolean value

Comment: **line #56** $query['conditions'] = array(); @AD7six

Comment: yes read.... but cant figure out what to do.. @AD7six

Comment: well that's disappointing - why not **look** at what `$query` is before assuming it's an array?

Comment: i found the solution... adding it as a answer to close the question. You are right @AD7six, this line is having problem '$query = parent::beforeFind($query);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [commentor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761202/ad7six) that $query is not an array, and beforeFind is returning boolean. So the following line is having problem.

```
$query = parent::beforeFind($query);
```

The correction is

There is no use of calling parent method as it is overridden it to implement own logic.

so the correct code is

```
public function beforeFind($query) {
            if(!isset($query['conditions'])){
            $query['conditions'] = array();
        }
        if(!$this->Authake->isAdmin()){
            if(empty($query['conditions']) || is_array($query['conditions'])){
                $query['conditions'] = array('organ_id' => $this->Organ->Group->getUserBranches());
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: ... If you're not using the return value of `parent::beforeFind` - why call it _at all_? I'm guessing the parent method is the base class [Model::beforeFind](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3598-L3600) - there is no reason or benefit calling the parent method if you've overridden it to implement your own logic.

Comment: Right.... I am just new to Cake. so little confused. it is working just fine without 'parent::beforeFind($query);' I am editing my answer